Are there any definitive, logical proof for Hinduism?
Is there any reason to absolutely believe that Hinduism is the truth, that is logical, and is not just a "Oh you just have to believe." This doesn't get asked a lot I suppose, and I am not of any particular religion, and I am more of less seeking knowledge by studying other religions. If there is not a logical proof for Hinduism, then is there any miracle in Hinduism that can be experienced, that is not subjective.
I'll give an example of an objective miracle from another religion: the Qur'an, which is a linguistic miracle, i.e. no human can create even a portion of it like it. This is objective, due to many reasons too long to explain here (I can if you wish, I've studied plenty of religions).
Is there anything like that in Hinduism? Some miracle that is tangible? Also, saying that any ritual or practice in Hinduism does so and so would not be considered one, as it is subjective. And I am fine with anyone bringing up other religions for anything, as long as you can provide the source. For example, if you are quoting from the Bible, mention the book, chapter, and verse number. For anything from Hinduism itself, I also ask for a source.
I seek to study religions, and I also ask no one to go out of their way to criticise others' religions with subjective or fallacious arguments, as I have seen more than plenty of people do it. So, please, enlighten me. Thank you to anyone who can answer me.

I would like to pay my respects to Lord Ved Vyasa, Maa Lakshmi, Lord Mukhyaprana and Lord Brahma, Maa Bharati and Maa Savitri, Lord Rudra and Maa Parvati, various other devatas and divine beings, and to all the Dwaita gurus. That eternal system that is practiced in higher abodes like Indraloka, Maharloka, Jnanaloka, Tapoloka, Shiva-loka, Brahma-loka, and Vaikuntha-loka, was revived by the highest Jiva-Atma Lord Mukhyaprana to counter the spread of perverse doctrines, like the wicked forms of monotheism that were being diffused in the mleccha-desas, and establish the presence of true monotheism in the sacred land of Bharata. While it is admissible to debate the tenets and arguments of a system spread by such a sacred and admirable being, it is wholly unacceptable to pretend to be a monotheist. The true God of a true monotheistic philosophy is an embodiment of absolute perfections. A true monotheist worships the true God, not a substitute. This is the offense committed by the poster of the question. May the Lord, His foremost Son Shri Hanumana-Bhima-Madhva, and all devatas be pleased with this rebuke.
Shri Hari-Vayu Gurubhyo Namah

At the outset, I also like to pay my respects to @AndthenIsaidMeow for pointing out that my previous answer was not logically sufficient. Just as the existence of evil allows one to know what is righteous and the existence of diseases allows one to strengthen his immune system and prevention techniques, the existence of such amusing oppositions to Tattvavaad allows one to improve the presentation of philosophy. Therefore, I am extremely grateful.
I: How to logically understand Sanatan Dharma (i.e. Shri Madhvacharya's philosophy) for those who accept monotheism
(This is adapted from Shri Jeevottamma Madhvacharya’s Tattva Sankhyaanaam, the great work that provides the simplest and strongest arguments for the existence of a personal God.)
The world we see contains composite entities. A composite entity is a dependent reality because it depends on its components. The universe is a composite entity and therefore is a dependent reality. It also consists of dependent realities. There cannot be an infinite chain of dependent realities because then nothing will ever come into existence. Therefore, these dependent realities depend on a common independent reality. Let us call this Brahman. Brahman must be a fundamental entity since a composite entity is a dependent reality. The dependent realities are controlled by Brahman and this requires the independent reality to be intelligent. Thus Brahman is an intelligent being who knows. Brahman just means God. Shriman Narayana is the Supreme Being.
Then, I note that the supremacy and blissfulness of Sarvotamma Narayana imply the eternality of the Jiva Atmas. Because the Supreme Lord is always perfectly blissful, He is eternally self-satisfied. Therefore He has no reason to create Jiva Atmas to worship Him or to punish. Since He is supreme, there can exist no agent that creates Jivas without His will. Hence Jiva Atmas were never created and eternally exist with Him.
Let us make the reasonable assumption that the number of Jiva Atmas is infinite. An Infinite number of Jiva Atmas imply the existence of unique intrinsic personalities. There are an infinite amount of Jiva Atmas, each unique from the others. Because there are infinite Jiva Atmas, there exists all possible intrinsic personalities which can be classified as follows: those who want to love God (mukti-yogas), those who want to remain in sense pleasures and not love God (nitya samsarins), and those who want to hate God and those who love Him (tamo yogas). There is a whole range of intrinsic natures that fall into the category of divine natures. The same is true for demonic natures and in-between natures. The mukti-yojas thrive in a blissful and loving environment filled with devotion towards Lord Narayana while the tamo yogas thrive in a painful and agonizing environment filled with hatred towards Lord Narayana.
Intrinsic natures of the Jiva Atmas imply the existence of the desire to achieve appropriate happiness and the incentive to immediately act to get that preferred bliss. Each Jiva Atma wants to achieve happiness that is on par with its intrinsic nature.They therefore have a natural incentive to act in a way to get their preferred happiness. No Jiva Atma is unsure of its intrinsic nature and therefore those who did not want to act at the very beginning (i.e. from the infinite past) are the ones whose intrinsic personality is to remain absolutely aloof from loving and hating God and the bondage of Maya. These Jiva Atmas would choose, in the very beginning, to remain in a coma-like state so that they are forever unaware of their surroundings. For them, happiness is no awareness and no experience.
Because the Supreme Lord is solely independent, all of the Jiva Atmas are under His control. They cannot act, grow, and develop on their own. How He controls them will be developed in the next couple of lines.
Omniscience of Sarvotamma Narayana implies predestination for everyone. The omniscience of Lord Narayana, who is not under the control of time, implies that He can see, at once, the exact trajectory each will take to meet its ultimate fate. He sees exactly how each Jiva Atma will forever respond to dharma, adharma, and karma. For an infinite being whose knowledge is perfect and infinite, “forever” is not unbounded and not unknown for Him.
Lord Narayana’s all-blissful, all-merciful, and perfectly just nature implies His desire for each Jiva Atma to grow and develop to their full potential and reach its desired state of happiness without successfully infringing on the intrinsically desired happiness of other Jiva Atmas. Therefore, Lord Narayana, from the very beginning, created a system of perfect justice based on cause and effect (or karma and phala) and placed the Jiva Atmas into eternal life. Karma is therefore a system that takes each Jiva Atma to its intrinsically preferred state appropriate for its exact nature. Jiva Atmas having divine (demonic) intrinsic natures will eventually reach Lord Narayana (eternal damnation in Andha-tamas, a place where immense pain and agony serve to reinforce these Jiva Atma's desire to hate Him and a place where these unique entities can thrive) and those whose intrinsic natures are in between the divine and the demonic are destined to stay forever in samsara and in the bondage of Maya. The grace of God is with everyone due to His perfect nature and everyone will reach their preferred salvation, but salvation does not need to mean attaining the abode of Lord Narayana. Lord Narayana’s all-merciful nature reflects the absence of an iota of bias in Him.
Note: Experience also shows that everyone’s life is different and therefore it is quite reasonable to say that the trajectories of two Jiva Atmas can never be the same (but can be very similar). The nature of trajectory is determined by the intrinsic nature. Therefore, no Jiva Atma’s intrinsic nature exactly matches that of another Jiva Atma; however, two Jiva Atmas can have very similar intrinsic nature
Lord Narayana’s all-blissful, all-merciful, and perfectly just nature implies He did not want to delay any Jiva Atma from achieving the perfection it intrinsically prefers. Therefore, He created His system of perfect justice and placed all of the Jiva Atmas into eternal life from the very beginning, i.e. in the infinite past.
All of this implies the existence of reincarnation from the infinite past. Each Jiva Atma wants to achieve happiness that is on par with its intrinsic nature. They therefore have a natural incentive to act in a way to grow and develop to their full potential and get their preferred happiness. Since they were placed into His system of perfect justice from the very beginning, all Jiva Atmas began to act from the very beginning. Currently, we all know we were born from our mother's womb and see ourselves acting. Since the Jiva Atma within my physical body has been acting from the infinite past, the Jiva Atma within my physical body has reincarnated and had lived as other beings in the past. This, in my opinion, is the true logic behind reincarnation that Shri Madhvacharya had just revived. The incorrect argument for reincarnation is that it answers the problem of suffering from birth. The correct argument for reincarnation rests on the unshakable conviction that the Supreme Lord is the embodiment of perfection and perfectly loves us all.
In Dwaita Vedanta God, Jiva Atmas, and jadas eternally coexist. The Supreme Lord perfectly knows the intrinsic nature of each Jiva Atma. In the infinite past, God created His perfect system of justice, used this system to guide the jadas, and placed the Jiva Atmas into eternal life. Since He completely knows the intrinsic nature and desire of each Jiva Atma and perfectly knows His system of justice, He knows the exact trajectories of each Jiva Atma. This universe of karma, rewards, and pains is perfectly just and will work in a way that gives each Jiva Atma what it intrinsically and ultimately prefers: perfection in loving God up to the Jiva Atma’s capacity (divine), perfection in loving only materialism up to one’s capacity (in-between), and perfection in hating God up to one’s capacity(demonic). The Jiva Atma will get what it intrinsically and ultimately wants forever but not everything it wants. Predestination is not God’s complete knowledge of what He wants from the Jiva Atmas because He is forever blissful and lacks nothing. Rather, predestination is God’s complete knowledge of His system of justice, what the Jiva Atmas intrinsically want from Him and Maya, and how they will respond to every situation they are confronted with. The Jiva Atmas forever depend on God to get and maintain what they intrinsically and ultimately want. The Jiva Atmas are the paratantra reality and the Supreme Lord is the swatantra reality.
Therefore, our mentality should be as follows:


What we intrinsically want will be determined by us and our choices and will only be given to us by God; therefore let us act honestly and diligently every moment and see what God and His system of justice have prepared for us and all.


As it can be seen, Vedic predestination is perfectly on par with the following famous verse from the Bhagavad Gita:


कर्मण्येवाधिकारस्ते मा फलेषु कदाचन |
मा कर्मफलहेतुर्भूर्मा ते सङ्गोऽस्त्वकर्मणि || 2.47 ||
karmaṇy-evādhikāras te mā phaleṣhu kadāchana
mā karma-phala-hetur bhūr mā te saṅgo ’stvakarmaṇi
You have a right to perform karma, but you are not in control of the results.
Never consider yourself to be the cause of these results and never be attached to inaction.


The Jiva Atmas, like the Supreme Lord, are beings with intrinsic personalities. The personality of the Jiva Atma present within each body is not the personality, due to the ahamkara, present in the conscious cognitive world. The latter dimly (i.e. not too accurately and not too inaccurately) reflects the former and are not unrelated: all conscious activities and decisions are influenced by unconscious processes.* Therefore, all conscious activities and decisions like individual will, personal choice, and adopted behaviors are influenced by the Jiva Atma’s intrinsic nature as the Jiva Atma remains in the woes and throes of samsara. Samsara is wholly controlled by the Supreme Lord, but conscious responses are controlled by the Jiva Atma. Is my (ahamkara) will free? No, it depends on something we (ahamkara) are not aware of.


*If there is the conscious feeling “I (ahamkara) am happy,” the Jiva Atma in the unconscious realms also feels happiness. Similarly, If there is the conscious feeling “I (ahamkara) am sad,” the Jiva Atma in the unconscious realms also feels pain.


Can conscious activities and decisions directly reveal whether the Jiva Atma inside is divine, demonic, or in-between? Not always. The divine, demonic, and in-between intrinsic natures are not synonymous with perfection. All who are not the Supreme Lord can be misguided, can make serious mistakes, and can be temporarily cursed into hellish existence; however, only conscious activities that eventually demonstrate the ability to introspect, learn from past mistakes, and improve themselves indicate the existence of a Jiva Atma with an intrinsic divine nature. For this reason, gurus must strive to appropriately educate society through brahma-vidya and righteous conduct because one cannot always know a priori whose Jiva Atma is intrinsically divine, demonic, and average. Patience is therefore important and one should not rashly reach a conclusion on the intrinsic nature of a Jiva Atma by some of the activities and lifestyles chosen by the ahamkara.
Consequently, pious activities like the study of scriptures and dharmic conduct are important despite the existence of predestination and intrinsic nature. The Jiva Atma will be active forever and the choices it will make will depend on its intrinsic nature. Only those Jiva Atmas who have intrinsic divine natures will continuously strive to enhance their devotion to God, perform righteous activities, study and recite scriptures, and espouse scriptural verses that encourage the performance of yagna/charity/tapas. All other Jiva Atmas will either stop caring about these activities or will intentionally and perversely perform activities that go against the scriptures. Predestination means the Supreme Lord completely knows, at once, all of the activities of the Jiva Atma for all time. Activities are therefore crucial aspects of predestination.


This, in my humble opinion, is Shri Madhvacharya's Tattvavaad (which is now known as Dvaita Vedanta) in a nutshell. Why is Shri Madhvacharya's siddhanta an objective miracle? Because amongst all monotheistic schools of thought, it alone follows from perfect logic and upholds the absolute perfection of God. No other God is as perfect as the God in Shri Madhvacharya's school. Only the true son of the true God can logically prove that his Father exists and only the true messenger of the true God can logically prove that his Lord exists. This is exactly what Shri Madhvacharya, i.e. Lord Mukhyaprana who is the son of Shriman Narayana, has done in his Tattva Sankhyaanaam. This is a literary miracle since no other imposter "son of God" or "messenger of God" has done that.


Why could not the mlecchas come up such logic? Something is indeed awry about the origin of the mleccha sampradayas and this can be understood by reading their scriptures. Like the poster of the question, I will assume that the events and messages in these scriptures have not changed over time.
II.If the Extant Versions of Mleccha Scriptures are Accurate of Their Origin, then the Mleccha Sampradayas and Their Scriptures are the Linguistic Miracles of Asuras like the Kali Purusha


[40] "In this Ghastly Kaliyuga where dharma is almost dead nobody bothers to remember All knowing Shri Madhwacharyaru who is the most favorite to Shri Veda Vyaasaru."
~ Shri Narayana Panditacharya in Madhwa Amrutha Maharnava


An important feature of this ghastly Kali Yuga is the modern versions of the mleccha sampradayas. The extant versions of their scriptures portray the devatas as demons and condemn teachings accepted by the Vedas. Many followers of these scriptures harbor such feelings. They spurn the worship of devatas, calling them demons who serve to delude man from God. They also call Lord Vishnu a rakshasa. They look down upon varnashrama dharma and condemn reincarnation as a false doctrine introduced by demonic beings to divide humans into a hierarchy. Vishnu-dwesha, Devata-dwesha and Veda-dwesha are to be condemned in the strongest possible terms and places, people, and books that contain these heresies are the abodes of the archfiend, the Kali Purusha. The Kali Purusha is the greatest hater of Shri Vishnu and Shri Mukhyaprana and therefore should be hated by all followers of Madhwa Shastra. The abodes of Kali Yuga should be spurned. One should always remember that the Kali Purusha resides with the mleccha sampradayas, the organizations that corrupted the holy and Vedic mleccha dharma mentioned in the Bhavishya Purana. Only those mlecchas who are Vishnu-haters, devata-haters, and Veda-haters are to be seen as pasus.
Consequently, it is important to recognize that the mleccha sampradayas do not worship the Vedic God Shriman Narayana. In the Mahabharata’s Vana Parva Sage Markandeya told the Pandavas the Kali Yuga would be filled with the worship of Eruka (evil) and kapata Brahma vaadis (i.e. corrupted preachers of God or preachers of false God). The mleccha sampradayas worship Eruka alone who progressively and divisively teaches them anti-Vedic philosophies such as the following:


You are not to craft for yourselves an idol or anything resembling what is in the skies above, or on earth beneath, or in the water sources under the earth. You are not to bow down to them in worship or serve them, because I, the Lord your God, am a jealous God, visiting the guilt of parents on children, to the third and fourth generation of those who hate me. (Exodus:20:4-5)




Nevertheless, I have a few things against you: There are some among you who hold to the teaching of Balaam, who taught Balak to entice the Israelites to sin so that they ate food sacrificed to idols and committed sexual immorality (Revelation 2:14)




Nevertheless, I have this against you: You tolerate that woman Jezebel, who calls herself a prophet. By her teaching she misleads my servants into sexual immorality and the eating of food sacrificed to idols (Revelation 2:20)


Why were not the mlecchas taught to offer food to God within the hearts and mouth of the devatas and then offer food to the devatas? Why were they not taught to respect all beings who are above them in an appropriate manner? Why were they not taught to pray to the devatas for devotion to God and the forces of good? One can still worship a devata without worshiping him as God. One can still have a favorite devata and not worship that devata as God. Maa Parvati and the Shiva ganas have a favorite devata (Lord Shiva) but they still worship Lord Vishnu’s Narasimha roopa as their God. These teachings are in stark contrast with the teachings of Shri Madhvacharya, the preacher of true monotheism. Such teachings have prepared the mlecchas to hate Sanatana dharma and its worship of devatas and God. These twisted teachings instruct the unqualified mlecchas to behave like the resplendent Ruju devatas, who are the highest Jivas who only worship Lord Vishnu and do not bow down to any other devata because of their position in the hierarchy; however, all true Ruju devatas are respected by the devatas, care deeply about the devatas below them, and believe in behavior appropriate to one’s position in the cosmic hierarchy. A true Ruju devata would never instruct humans to hate and disrespect devatas and their idols. A true Ruju devata, like Shri Madhvacharya, would instruct men to be devoted to God and worship the devatas as beings higher than man but lower than God. A true Ruju devata would teach true monotheism that appropriately includes all forms of worship. Only a demon, who greatly hates the Ruju devatas for their extreme devotion to God, would dare to impersonate a Ruju devata and teach a perverted version of their glorious teachings.
For a more detailed example consider, for instance, the life of the innocent-minded Mohammad narrated in the Qu'ran. A summary of this simple-hearted man's life can be found in this Wikipedia link. An important part of his life is summarized in the following verses that narrate his encounter with Gabriel:


The financial security Muhammad enjoyed from Khadija, his wealthy wife, gave him plenty of free time to spend in solitude in the cave of Hira.[74][75] According to Islamic tradition, one day in 610 CE, when he was 40 years old, the angel Gabriel appeared to him during his visit to the cave. The angel showed him a cloth with Quranic verses on it and instructed him to read. When Muhammad confessed his illiteracy, Gabriel choked him forcefully, nearly suffocating him, and repeated the command. As Muhammad reiterated his inability to read, Gabriel choked him again in a similar manner. This sequence took place once more before Gabriel finally recited the verses, allowing Muhammad to memorize them.[76][77][78] These verses later constituted Quran 96:1-5.[79]




When Muhammad came to his senses, he felt scared; he started to think that after all of this spiritual struggle, he had been visited by a jinn, which made him no longer want to live. In desperation, Muhammad fled from the cave and began climbing up towards the top of the mountain to jump to his death. But when he reached the summit, he experienced another vision, this time seeing a mighty being that engulfed the horizon and stared back at Muhammad even when he turned to face a different direction…Frightened and unable to understand the experience, Muhammad hurriedly staggered down the mountain to his wife….Nonetheless, these enigmatic seizure events might have served as persuasive evidence for his followers regarding the divine origin of his revelations. Some historians posit that the graphic descriptions of Muhammad's condition in these instances are likely genuine, as they are improbable to have been concocted by later Muslims.[88][89]


Gabriel’s behavior does not reflect that of a divine being like a devata. No devata, or divine spirit, will physically abuse an innocent and illiterate man when he could not carry out orders but would immediately find means to help that man. Only asuras have the mentality of losing their cool when their self interests are hindered. It took Gabriel three times until he decided to read the verses so that Muhammad could memorize them. If Gabriel was a devata he would have immediately read the verses to Muhammad after learning about his illiteracy or would have blessed him with a boon to read. Did not Maa Saraswati bless the illiterate Kalidasa with knowledge? Devatas, and other divine beings, have the power to give auspicious boons like knowledge while asuras do not.
Kirtivasa’s Bengali rendition of the Ramayana narrates an encounter between Ratnakara dasyu and two devatas, Lord Brahmadev (a Ruju devata like Lord Mukhyaprana) and Sage Narada. Both these devatas gracefully endured the abuses of the dasyu such as being tied to a tree. When Ratnakara dasyu could not utter the name of Lord Rama, the two devatas thought of a clever way to make him eventually repeat the name of God properly. They did not choke him due to his inability but showed their true divine character. The demeanor of Lord Brahmadeva and Devarsi Narada are at odds with that of Gabriel. Gabriel was thus a demonic being who came under the guise of an angel to manipulate the innocent Muhammad and fulfill a mission of the asuras but could not hide his asuric nature for long.
Another interesting fact is Muhammad’s immediate reaction to the visit: he was scared. When a true devata visits a human, he feels a sense of bliss and gets relieved from some pain. This reflects the divine nature of the visitor. In contrast, when a demonic being visits a human, the person experiences negative results: when King Nala and King Parikshit were possessed by the Kali Purusha they lost their sense of wisdom and succumbed to evil and emotional behavior. These negative results reveal the demonic nature of the visitor. Muhammad experienced negative results like fear and seizures. A devata would never torment a human whom he had visited. Consequently, the effulgent being Muhammad saw while in the mountain could not be a divine being or God, but a demonic being who was posing himself as God to spread a false religion.
Now consider the following verses from the same Wikipedia page:


According to Amr ibn al-As, several of the Quraysh gathered at Hijr and discussed how they had never faced such serious problems as they were facing from Muhammad. They said that he had derided their culture, denigrated their ancestors, scorned their faith, shattered their community, and cursed their gods… Along with many others,[130] Tabari recorded that Muhammad was desperate, hoping for an accommodation with his tribe. So, while he was in the presence of a number of Quraysh, after delivering verses mentioning three of their favorite deities (Quran 53:19–20), Satan put upon his tongue two short verses: "These are the high flying ones / whose intercession is to be hoped for." This led to a general reconciliation between Muhammad and the Meccans, and the Muslims in Abyssinia began to return home. However, the next day, Muhammad retracted these verses at the behest of Gabriel, claiming that they had been cast by Satan to his tongue and God had abrogated them. Instead, verses that revile those goddesses were then revealed.


From Gabriel, the innocent Muhammad learned to vilify the gods. Deva-nindya is a serious offense according to Hindu scriptures. The same scriptures reveal that deva-nindya is a characterization of the Kali Yuga. The true Vedic monotheism was reestablished by Shri Madhvacharya and he never vilified the devatas. In fact he encouraged the proper worship of the various divinities who were not Param Atma Shriman Narayana by instructing his followers to see them as beings greater than humans and to pray to them for devotion to Vishnu. Shri Madhvacharya’s method of establishing monotheism is starkly different from the way Gabriel established monotheism through Muhammad, revealing the divine nature of Shri Madhvacharya and the demonic nature of Gabriel. Only demons vilify the gods and only a true Ruju devata will tell others to respect and worship the divinities properly.
It is also interesting to note who these goddesses were. Their images are found in this Wikipedia link and one notices that the idol resembles that of Maa Bhagavati Durga-devi. The same article reveals how many Muslims after Muhammad believed the images of this goddess were shipped to India for safe keeping while the other images in Arabia were destroyed. Gabriel had thus instructed Muhammad to insult Devi Durga, a revered goddess in Bhagavata dharma. This further reveals that Gabriel was a demon and that Muhammad was getting instructions to spread the worship of a false God.
All of this is a consequence of him being possessed and manipulated by the demon Gabriel. Shri Madhvacharya’s monotheism does not portray this type of anti-devata bigotry and no true God will promote such kind of un-Vedic practice.
It is important to note that the true God sends messengers to (1) give and maintain true knowledge among a group of people or (2) destroy ignorance. If the mleccha sampradayas were actually started by the messengers of the true God then either (1) or (2) would be present with them because God has infinite powers to bless the people He wants to rescue. However, the opposites of (1) and (2) have been occurring in the mleccha sampradayas a little time after their founding. These effects strongly suggest their cause was not divine but demonic.
One should never believe that mleccha sampradayas worship the true God Lord Narayana. Believing that they do and incorporating their prayers and worship into our Vedic dharma show ignorance and through ignorance sin will flourish. The mleccha sampradayas are sinful and should be condemned on the strongest possible terms.
III: Concluding Remarks
Our Lord Vishnu is an embodiment of infinite perfections and auspicious qualities. He is absolutely and incessantly blissful at all times and never has intrinsic hatred for anyone, not even towards those souls who want to hate Him. He is not a capricious tyrant but a judicious monarch who is the embodiment of perfect justice who unbiasly administers the predestined fates of Jiva Atmas. He gives some souls liberation and other souls eternal perdition, but unlike your Allah He never hates -- He is too judicious and perfect to have those blemishes. Similarly, His messenger during the Kali Yuga, though bold and unrelenting in his devotion to Lord Narayana, is of impeccable character unlike your demon Gabriel. Shri Madhvacharya's siddhanta is the only light in the dark age of Kali Yuga and only his philosophy reflects the perfect monotheism enshrined in the Rik, Sama, Yajur, Atharvan, Ithihasas, and Puranas. Everything else is heresy. Your Allah is imperfect and his messengers and devotees are against the devotees of Lord Vishnu (like the devatas) and against Lord Vishnu Himself. My head can be forcibly removed my the rest of my body but it will never ever bow down to such sinners.
Enough of these false dharmas! Why the hell don't the Hindus condemn them more sternly? A bunch of cowards and napunsakas!
There is one God Ishwara Param Atma and in the land of Bharata, Shri Anandatirtha Bhagavadpadacharya was His chief (Mukhya) prophet.
All of the reasons outlined above are due to the grace of the Hari-Vayu Guru alone. I do not wish to take credit for it nor do I want anyone to give me credit for it.
Bharatiramanamukhyapranaantargata Shri Krishnaarpanamastu

Update: In this response, I tried to be as non-sectarian as possible, but I acknowledge that this answer is not logically sufficient, as the question poster’s comments reveal. I will give a sectarian answer later. A friendly warning: that answer will be offensive to some Hindus, especially those who do not agree with Dvaita Vedanta of Shri Madhvacharya. I hope they will tolerate that response. I am not interested in how non-Hindus will react to my, hopefully logical, answer. May Shri Hari-Vayu guru be pleased with it.
That Hinduism still survives and thrives in Bharatavarsa (India) after Islamic and Christian rule is itself an objective miracle. That Hinduism is still being fervently practiced and taught in the monasteries established by Shri Madhvacharya, Shri Ramanujacharya, and Shri Sankaracharya (etc) even after the brutal destruction of hindu temples by the Islamic crusaders is another objective miracle. That the small percentage of Jews living in Bharat since the times of the Exodus have not been slaughtered to extinction by the Islamic crusaders is another objective miracle.
Other places weren't as lucky as the holy land of Bharat. That is another objective miracle.
Vande mataram


If I went back in time and asked someone who believed Zeus why Greek mythology is true, and he just said "it lasted for 1000 years", that doesn't make it true. Older something is makes it less truer matter of fact, for you have left to prove whether it has been preserved. Literally anything can last forever if it can change, but if Hinduism was indeed from God, it shouldn't be changeable. God, All-Knowing enough, should be able to reveal a religion applicable for all time. This is literally, "It's old, no one could destroy it, thus it's true". It's illogical, hence isn't acceptable.

@AndthenIsaidMeow but the author actually means Greek religion was destroyed by christian civilization but India wasn't. As per Hindu scriptures we are currently living in Kali Yuga where dharma declines by each passing year. It is indeed true that Dharma is declining day by day and it can be the definitive proof of hinduism which you asked for.

Well, the crusades didn't take out Islam nor did Islam take out Christianity from Europe. Just because its surviving isn't proof.

@AndthenIsaidMeow You mentioned in your post "then is there any miracle in Hinduism that can be experienced, that is not subjective." You wanted to know some objective miracles concerning Sanatan dharma and I provided some. That was the scope of my answer. I am not interested in convincing you that Sanatan dharma is the true religion. Also you suggested in your comments that Hinduism is a polytheistic religion. It is not. Philosophical schools of Vedanta are either monistic (like Advaita) or monotheistic (like Visisthadvaita and Dvaita).

@AndthenIsaidMeow In these monotheistic schools, the devatas (gods) are not worshiped as God, while Lord Vishnu is worshiped as the Supreme Being (God) who is the granter of liberation and the cause of the cosmos. In these schools, particularly, in Dvaita Vedanta, the devatas are revered as powerful devotees of Lord Vishnu whose devotion to God are revered and extolled. These monotheistic schools of Vedanta stem from the ancient Bhagavata sect of Vaishnavas. The monistic schools like Advaita adopt a more henotheistic approach where every devata is a manifestation of Brahman.

@AndthenIsaidMeow These schools have existed prior to the introduction of Islam in India. Monotheism and monism have been practiced before the arrival of Abrahamic faiths in the Indian subcontinent and have survived (along with their works like commentaries and hymns) to this day. Therefore, I wouldn't say religion in India is polytheistic.

@AndthenIsaidMeow I only agree with you on one thing: that religion in India (which you call Hinduism) has diversified over the centuries and that Sanatan dharma (i.e. eternal religion) is unchangeable. I personally am a monotheistic hindu, a dvaitin in fact, but I have no interest in pitting one sect of hinduism with another one, especially in a conversation that obviously (maybe intentionally or unintentionally) tries to demean the Vedas, the devatas, and Lord Vishnu. No dvaitin, or any Hindu for that matter, will ever accept a religion that is anti-Vedic, anti-devata, and anti-Vishnu.

@AndthenIsaidMeow As a dvaitin, I firmly belief that the monotheism in Abrahamic faiths is temporary while the grand and flawless monotheism revived and propounded by Shri Madhvacharya, who in my humble and honest opinion is the true son and messenger of the true God, is the eternal nature of reality. And I firmly believe that Shri Madhvacharya's sect will survive the onslaughts from the mlecchas and their blasphemous forms of monotheism propounded from the influence of the Kalipurusha. Peace. Shri Hari-Vayu Gurubhyo Nama. Bharatiramanamukhyapranaantargata Shri Krishnaarpanamastu.

The reason for Survival of Abrahamic religions in India is that there is no conversion allowed in Hinduism and the other one is adhering to tolerance because the entire philosophy stems from Karma. However, ISKCON supports some kind conversion, so it is spreading world wide!

@Marmayogi So true...but I think we Hindus should have been a bit stricter with the Abrahamics (except the Jews, who have never bothered us)

@Marmayogi" no conversion allowed in Hinduism" pretty true. Even the hard-core Dvaitins are more interested in condemning than in converting.
