Is Kali Purusha a devata?
Most of us consider Kali Purusha is an asura. But, this chapter of Vana Parva described him as the vilest among the devas:-

Hearing this, Indra said with a smile, 'That Swayamvara is already ended. In our sight she hath chosen Nala for her husband.' Thus answered by Sakra, Kali, that vilest of the celestials, filled with wrath, addressing all those gods spake, 'Since in the presence of the celestials she hath chosen a mortal for her lord, it is meet that she should undergo a heavy doom.'

Despite this, when Asuras met Duryodhana, they describe him as "divine" and created by Lord Shiva and Parvati (as i discussed about it, here). And, sometimes Kali is considered as Gandharva (But, In my point of view, Kali Purusha and Gandharva Kali are diffrent.)
So, my question is, Is Kali Purusha devata? If yes, do any scripture mention about his idenity as devata?

Hello, I think "they describe him as "divine" and created by Lord Shiva and Parvati" just refers to the body of Duryodhana and not to the soul known as Kali Purusha.

"And, sometimes Kali is considered as Gandharva (But, In my point of view..." I also agree. If I remember correctly during the Adi Parva's description of Arjuna's birth, the Mahabharata text mentions how various divine beings arrived and celebrated. One of the beings was called Kali (not Kaali). I cannot imagine that the Kali Purusha, who incarnated as Duryodhana, would celebrate the birth of a divine hero who played an important role in crushing the demonic forces.

"Kali, that vilest of the celestials" That is just an English translation. A celestial technically can be ANY being who is flying in the skies. During the Mahabharata war various beings watched from the sky, including the devatas and the asuras. They even picked sides during the famous battle between Arjuna and Karna in the Karna Parva. Maybe the Sanskrit verse is slightly different? There's probably some Sanskrit version of the Mahabharata on hinduscriptures.in

I think the Kali Purusha is an asura. Maybe he is the one who talked to Moses and the Israelites from the sky ("You are not to craft for yourselves an idol or anything resembling what is in the skies above, or on earth beneath, or in the water sources under the earth. You are not to bow down to them in worship or serve them, because I, the Lord your God, am a jealous God, visiting the guilt of parents on children, to the third and fourth generation of those who hate me. (Exodus:20:4-5)") or the one who sent the "angel" Gabriel to choke Mohammad to submission (see Wikipedia page on Mohammad).

The above things are what Kali would do. Have you ever noticed that शैतान sounds like Satan? :)

Even in the Bhavishya Purana it is mentioned, I think, that the Kali Purusha received a boon from Lord Narayana that the mlecchas would grow in population during the Kali Yuga....Hmm maybe we know why most of the world consists of mlecchas and the dominating religions are the mleccha sampradayas who intrinsically have an anti-Sanatan dharma bias. That wretch Kali Purusha did it all...this doesn't sound like the doings of a devata does it?

Kali Purusha is the personification of the Kali Yuga. He is often portrayed as a demon of Kali Yuga who symbolizes the deterioration of dharma in this age and finds its earliest mention in the Mahabharata. The beginning of the Kalki Purana describes Kali's lineage starting with Brahma, his great-great-grandfather, and ending with the birth of his children's children.
He is the presiding ruler over the Kali Yuga. He is most commonly found in places with alcohol, drugs, gambling, adultery, and uncleanliness to name a few.
Kalki Purana [chapter-1] describes Kali-Yuga answering, Who is Kali? Where was he born? How did he become the master of the world? How does he destroy the observance of eternal religious principles? [sloka-6]
Maharishi Sūta says about the birth of Kali Purusha in detail:

After the annihilation, the secondary creator of the universe, Lord
Brahma, the grandfather of everyone, who was born on the universal
lotus flower, created Sin personified, having a black complexion,
from his back. [Sloka-14]
The name of Sin personified was Adharma By faithfully hearing
about, chanting, and remembering the descendents of Adharma, one
quickly becomes freed from all sinful reactions. [Sloka-15]
The wife of Adharma (Irreligion), was named Mithya (Falsehood) She
was very beautiful, and had eyes like those of a cat They had a son
named Dambha (Pride), who was always very angry and energetic.
[Sloka-16]
Dambha had a sister named Māyā, and within her womb, he begot a son
named Lobha (Greed), and a daughter named Nikrti (Cunning) Lobha
begot a son named Krodha (Anger), in the womb of Nikrti. [Sloka-17]
Himsa (Envy), was Krodha's sister. From the womb of Himsa, Krodha
begot a son named Kali. Kali Purusha is always seen to be holding his
genitals in his left hand. His complexion is very black, like black
ointment that has been mixed with oil. [Sloka-18]
Kali's abdomen is like that of a crow, his face is frightening to
behold, and his tongue is red and appears to be full of greed. His
appearance is very fearful and a bad smell emanates from his body.
Kali is very fond of playing chess, drinking wine, enjoying the
company of prostitutes, and associating with gold merchants.
[Sloka-19]
Kali's sister was Durukti (Harsh Speech). From Durukti's womb, Kali
begot a son named Bhaya (Fear), and a daughter named Mrtyu (Death).
Bhaya begot a son named Niraya (Hell) from the womb of Mrtyu and
Niraya begot ten thousand sons in the womb of his sister, Yatana
(Excessive Pain). Thus I have described the destructive progeny of
Kali, who were all blasphemers of genuine religious principles.
[Sloka-20 and 21]
All these relatives of Kali were the destroyers of sacrifice, study
of the Vedas, and charity, because they transgressed all the Vedic
principles of religion. They were reservoirs of mental distress,
disease, old age, destruction of religious principles, sorrow,
lamentation, and fear. [Sloka-22]
These descendents of Kali are found wandering everywhere throughout
the kingdom of Kali, destroying the people of the world They are
misguided by the influence of time, very restless by nature, full of
lusty desires, extremely sinful, very proud, and violent even to
their own father and mother Those who are known as twice-born among
them are devoid of all good behavior, without any observance of
proper etiquette, and always engaged in the service of sudras.
[Sloka-23 and 24]


Nice answer, btw.

@Debbie Thanks for the comments.

And thank you for the last time you kicked this pro-Allah and anti-Hindu cockroach in its ass through your comments under that creature's post: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61444/are-there-any-definitive-logical-proof-for-hinduism/61447#61447

Thanks @Debbie , I take it as compliments!

Yeah, indeed I was complimenting you (i.e. I was NOT being sarcastic but honest)

Got it. Thanks!
