What is anadi? Is innumerable past janmas theory valid?
If some action exists then it must be quantifiable..How can there be innumerable past births? There must be a number..
I want answer especially from Dwaita and Vishishtadwaita point of view..

Innumerable past janmas according to Dvaita (Tattvavaad) follows from the absolute perfection of God. See the longer answer here which was my attempt to give a reason for reincarnation (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61444/are-there-any-definitive-logical-proof-for-hinduism/61447#61447). Sorry if the language seems harsh, but it was appropriate for the anti-Hindu tone in the posted question. Also, the phrase "from the very beginning" means "from the infinite past."

"If some action exists then it must be quantifiable": that is sort of correct. A better (in my humble opinion) answer is "if some action exists then it must countable, i.e. we can say birth 1, birth 2, birth 3,..." where birth 1 is used to denote the present birth, birth 2 is used to denote the birth prior to this one, etc. This list is countable but infinite like the set of positive integers.

When did reality begin? From the infinite past, i.e. it always existed and therefore is without beginning (anadi). If one considers reincarnation to be reality, which logically follows from the absolute perfection of Shriman Narayana, then why can't he assume that reincarnation always existed and we are without beginning? If you did not hesitate to accept that reality always existed, why are you hesitating to accept that reincarnation always existed? Are you hesitating to accept that God is absolutely perfect? If so, then you might be possessed by an asura who wants to blasphemy God.

You might need an exorcism :). Shri Madhva Shiddanta is uncompromising when it comes to the perfection of Shriman Vishnu. Shri Vishnu is ABSOLUTELY perfect. NOT A SINGLE FLAW EXISTS IN THAT SUPREME LORD, THAT GOD OF GODS, THAT KING OF KINGS. Philosophies that make God imperfect, though perhaps well-intended, are durbhasyas (flawed commentaries) and asat shastras (false scriptures).

I) Your first question What is anadi?
Anādi(अनादि) is an important term in vedānta which means Beginningless. For instance, Brahman is anādi, Karma is anādi, Jīvātman is anādi, Māyā is anādi, etc.
1) Bhagavad Gita [Chapter 13, Verse 13] says Brahman (The Absolute) is anādi:

 ज्ञेयं यत्तत्प्रवक्ष्यामि यज्ज्ञात्वामृतमश्रुते 
 अनादिमत्परं ब्रह्म न सत्तन्नासदुच्यते || १३ ||

I shall now reveal to you that which ought to be known, and by knowing
which, one attains immortality. It is the beginningless Brahman, which
lies beyond existence and non-existence.

and 2) Mandūkya upanishad [1.16] says Māyā is anādi:

 अनादिमायया सुप्तो यदा जीवः प्रबुध्यते ।
 अजमनिद्रमस्वप्नमद्वैतं बुध्यते तदा ॥ १६ ॥
 anādimāyayā supto yadā jīvaḥ prabudhyate |
 ajamanidramasvapnamadvaitaṃ budhyate tadā || 16 ||

When the Jīva or the individual soul sleeping (i.e., not knowing the
Reality) under the influence of the beginningless Māyā, is awakened,
it, then, realizes (in itself) the non-duality, beginningless and
dreamless.

II) Your second and final question Is innumerable past Janmas theory valid?
Answer is Yes.
1) Bhagavad Gita [Chapter 16, Verse 19-20], asserts that punarjanma is possible forever as follows:
 तानहं द्विषत: क्रूरान्संसारेषु नराधमान् |
 क्षिपाम्यजस्रमशुभानासुरीष्वेव योनिषु || १९ ||

 These cruel haters, worst of men, I hurl these evil-doers for ever in
 the worlds into the wombs of the demons only.|| 19||

 आसुरीं योनिमापन्ना मूढा जन्मनि जन्मनि |
 मामप्राप्यैव कौन्तेय ततो यान्त्यधमां गतिम् || २० ||

 Entering into demoniac wombs, the deluded ones, in birth after birth,
 without ever reaching Me, O son of Kunti, pass into a condition still
 lower than that.|| 20||

2) Thiruvalluva Muni (तिरुवल्लुव मुनि/திருவள்ளுவர்) in his Thirukkural(तिरुक्कुरल्/திருக்குறள்), a Tamil Spiritual Granta about Purushārtam(पुरुषार्थम्/Four ultimate goals of human life viz. Dharma, Artha, Kāma and Moskha respectively in Hinduism), delineates in 10th sloka(out of 1,330) the following:

பிறவிப் பெருங்கடல் நீந்துவர் நீந்தார்
இறைவன் அடிசேரா தார். ॥ 10 ॥

Swim Ocean of Cycle of Birth, those who does(swim successfully) will
reach the feet of God(Brahman), others (those who do not) will drown.॥ 10 ॥

This kural [10] asserts that Punarjanmas(पुनर्जन्म/Reincarnation) are innumerable and countless using the term "Ocean of Rebirths"!

and 3) Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam [4.21.31] says punarjanma is innumerable as below:

 यत्पादसेवाभिरुचिस्तपस्विना-मशेषजन्मोपचितं मलं धिय: ।
 सद्य: क्षिणोत्यन्वहमेधती सती यथा पदाङ्गुष्ठविनि:सृता सरित् ॥ ३१ ॥
 yat-pāda-sevābhirucis tapasvinām aśeṣa-janmopacitaṁ malaṁ dhiyaḥ
 sadyaḥ kṣiṇoty anvaham edhatī satī yathā padāṅguṣṭha-viniḥsṛtā sarit. ॥31॥

By the inclination to serve the lotus feet of the Supreme Personality
of Godhead, suffering humanity can immediately cleanse the dirt which
has accumulated in their minds during innumerable births. Like the
Ganges water, which emanates from the toes of the lotus feet of the
Lord, such a process immediately cleanses the mind, and thus spiritual
or Kṛṣṇa consciousness gradually increases.॥ 31 ॥


Madhvāchārya differed significantly from traditional Hindu beliefs owing to his concept of eternal damnation. According to him, there are three different classes of souls(Jīvas): One class, Mukti-yogyas (eligible for mukti), which would qualify for liberation, another, the Nitya-samsārins, which would be subject to eternal punarjanma (eternal reincarnation) and a third class, Tamo-yogyas, which would be condemned to eternal hellish life (Andhatāmisra/अन्धतामिस्र/Complete darkness of the soul).
Madhva believed that some souls are eternally doomed and damned, a view not found in Advaita and Vishishtādvaita Vedanta. While the Vishishtādvaita Vedanta (Rāmānujar) asserted "qualitative monism and quantitative pluralism of souls", Madhva asserted both "qualitative and quantitative pluralism of souls".
Good Luck!

Thanks sir..but how can there be countless janmas? There must be a number..

Are there any more scriptural references which say there are innumerable past janmas?

@Marmayogi "Madhvāchārya differed significantly from traditional Hindu beliefs owing to his concept of eternal damnation. According to him..." It depends what you mean by "traditional." Shri Jeevottamma Madhvacharya differed from other Indian phisophers but that does not mean his philosophy is some new form of Sanatan Dharma. Shri Madhvacharya's school of thought follows logically from the absolute perfection of Shriman Narayana. Thus Shri Madhvacharya's ideas are not just "his personal opinions" but ideas rooted in solid logic.

@Marmayogi See the longer answer in (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61444/are-there-any-definitive-logical-proof-for-hinduism/61447#61447) for my humble attempt to justify Shri Madhvacharya's school.

If you say that Madhvāchīrya's ideas rooted in solid logic, then do you mean Shankara and Rāmānuja were illogical? All the three Āchāryās established their philosophies based on Vedas by using pramanas that supported them. It is valid. Nevertheless, both Ramanuja and Madva supported Pratyaksha, Anumana and Shruti pramana. Question is Based on what pramana did Madhvacharya arrive at the concept of eternal damnation? [Cont..]

Bear in mind that no philosophy (including religions shaiva, vaishnava, sākta, gānapatya, soura and koumāram) under Hinduism supports eternal damnation (or division amongst jīvas). @Debbie , My opinion is that it should be on the influence of BG [16.19-20] as mentioned before [refer II.1 above].  I see this as Madhvāchīrya's point of view. Many may not accept, but that kind of point of view should also be welcomed! Otherwise why should we need three philosophies based on vedas, in the first place?

@Marmayogi Thanks for your comments. As to the quote "If you say that Madhvāchīrya's ideas rooted in solid logic, then do you mean Shankara and Rāmānuja were illogical?" by answer for Shri Ramanuja is he was not illogical per se but did not consider all possibilities. If there are an infinite number of Jiva Atmas, each of whom are persons, then there exists all possible kinds of intrinsic natures. This would not be the case for a finite number of Java Atmas. All possible  personalities can be classified into three broad groups:

@Marmayogi (1) those who intrinsically want to love God, (2) those who intrinsically prefer to hate God, and (3) those who do neither care about God nor hate God and want to go after material pleasures. Thus starting from "infinite number of Jiva Atmas" one can use inference and logic (anumana pramana) to conclude the existence of (1) muktiyogas (2) tamoyogas and (3) nitya samsarins. Hence Shri Madhvacharya's ideas on liberation, eternal damnation, and eternal transmigration follow from inference alone.

@Marmayogi If there are an infinite number of souls, what is preventing a soul who intrinsically hates God from existing? Thus we see that Shri Madhvacharya's classification of souls is considers all possibilities and therefore is comprehensive.

@Marmayogi As for Shri Adi Sankaracharya's Advaita Vedanta (I don't mean to be dismissive or anything) the two fundamental arguments he uses to establish non-duality and that Brahman's true nature cannot have activity contain subtle, but important, logical errors and are not exactly on par with "infinity" and the verse the Advaita school calls the swaroop lakshana. Thus one can argue that the Advaitic school's interpretation follows from a lack of understanding of their own swaroop lakshana. How can Advaita be on solid logical footings? (again, I don't mean to be dismissive)

@Marmayogi However, Shri Madhvacharya's ideas, along with the verses he quotes in his Brahma Sutra Bhasya, show a very good conceptual understanding of uncountable infinity several centuries before the mlecchas rigorously constructed uncountable infinity. See this (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/60178/refuting-sa-atma-atat-tvam-asi-of-madhava-paingala-upanishad/60282#60282) for what I mean.

@Marmayogi "Bear in mind that no philosophy (including religions shaiva, vaishnava, sākta, gānapatya, soura and koumāram) under Hinduism supports eternal damnation." Yes, I know, but how does that make Shri Madhvacharya's philosophy a deviation from the true purport of the Vedas? No philosophy under Hinduism, except Dvaita Vedanta, shows a remarkably accurate understanding of infinity. Doesn't that make Dvaita special?

@Marmayogi "Based on what pramana did Madhvacharya arrive at the concept of eternal damnation? " That's a tricky question because did Shri Madhvacharya give his interpretation of the Vedas or did he reveal the lost religion of Bharatvarsa? Keep in mind that Shri Madhvacharya, according to Dvaita tradition, repeated the intent of Lord Veda Vyasa and did not just give his own interpretations. If one challenges whether Shri Madhvacharya actually went to Lord Veda Vyas then one can point out Shri Madhvacharya converted his own guru. His guru would have been aware if Shri Madhva never went.

@Marmayogi If one challenges whether Shri Madhvacharya actually went to Lord Veda Vyas one can humbly challenge whether Shri Ādi Sankarāchāryā went to Lord Veda Vyas (the meeting is discussed in Sankara Vijaya of Shri Vidyaranya). See the same link ()https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/60178/refuting-sa-atma-atat-tvam-asi-of-madhava-paingala-upanishad/60282#60282

@Marmayogi If Advaita is the true purport of the Vedas then the logic the school uses to analyze Vedic verses and arrive at the shiddhanta of non-duality must be flawless for only a bhasya that is an embodiment of logical perfection can reveal the Truth. Therefore, a bhasya based on logical errors cannot be the true purport of the Vedas and therefore is a durbhasya (again, I am not trying to be disrespectful). When you ask "If you say that Madhvāchīrya's ideas rooted in solid logic, then do you mean Shankara... [was] illogical?" my humble answer is yes and the errors are mentioned in that link

@Marmayogi again, I am not trying to be disrespectful and I am sorry if sentiments are hurt.
